# is it possible to add a constant string before appending?

Tags: python

Trying to Use boto3 for creating dashboards. How to add a Constant string before appending or Is there any other method available?

```
a = [1,2,3,4...]
```

i need

```
[ "AWS/ElasticMapReduce", "MemoryAvailableMB", "JobFlowId", "1" ],
[ "AWS/ElasticMapReduce", "MemoryAvailableMB", "JobFlowId", "2" ],
[ "AWS/ElasticMapReduce", "MemoryAvailableMB", "JobFlowId", "3" ],
[ "AWS/ElasticMapReduce", "MemoryAvailableMB", "JobFlowId", "4" ]
```

I'm doing:

```
a = [1,2,3]
x = []

for y in a:
    x.append("AWS/ElasticMapReduce", "MemoryAvailableMB", "JobFlowId", "y")
print x
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: @rotwar The answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking but you can get your desired output from your code if you change the line inside the `for` loop to the following: `x.append(["AWS/ElasticMapReduce", "MemoryAvailableMB", "JobFlowId", str(y)])`

Comment: @pault Thanks, I think, that is what i'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

your code can be fixed like this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
x = []

for y in a:
    x.append(["AWS/ElasticMapReduce", "MemoryAvailableMB", "JobFlowId", y])
print (x)
```

Note that this doesn't make the original integers in `a` into strings... (use `str(y)` in the loop to do that)